# c++ 2D array allocation

Tags: c++

Could someone please explain what each line is really doing here. I know overall it allocates 4 spaces, but I don't understand the details.

```
        int** arrayArray; 
        arrayArray= new int*[4];
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
        { arrayArray[x] = new int[4];}
```

Comment: overall it allocates memory for 4*4=16 integers and not 4.

Comment: @Atri should it say  say                                                                                                        
        int ** arrayArray= new int*[4];
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
        { arrayArray[x] = new int[2];}

Comment: Do you want to allocate space for 4 integers?

Comment: @Altri yes 4 integers

Comment: You can accept the answer that you think answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int** arrayArray; 
arrayArray= new int*[4];
```

The above code initializes 4 locations that can hold pointers to 4 `int*`

The next couple of lines allocate 4 int spaces for each `int*`, so a total of 4*4=16 integer spaces.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
{ arrayArray[x] = new int[4];}
```

Now as per your comment, you want only 4 integer spaces. So that means your 2d array would be 2x2.

So your code should look something like:

```
int** arrayArray; 
arrayArray= new int*[2];
for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
{ arrayArray[x] = new int[2];}
```

This way you will only allocate 2 `int*` locations and 2 int spaces that they can point to.

Answer (score 3):

Your array is a 2D array, so it size is in forms of "x by y". The total `int`s your array contains will be x*y. I will call x as the row number and y as the column number.

It seems like you need a array with total 4 `int`s, so your row number and column number should have a product of 4, for example 2x2. Keep in mind that the following answer is dealing with a 4x4 array, which has 16 total `int`s.

**Allocation**:

```
int** arrayArray;
```

This line decelar a variable `arrayArray`, which is a pointer of ( pointer of `int` ). Like

```
(arrayArray) -> * -> int
```

So `arrayArray[0]` gives you a pointer of `int`, and `arrayArray[0][0]` therefore give you an `int` (which is in the array).

```
arrayArray = new int*[4];
```

This line allocate a space that can contain 4 pointers of `int`, and set the `arrayArray` to point to that space (don't forget that `arrayArray` is **a pointer of a pointer of `int`**. ).

Here the `4` means row number.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    arrayArray[x] = new int[4];
```

For every pointer in `arrayArray`, set it to point to a space for 4 `int`s.

Here the 4 in `new int[4]` means column number.

So the structure of this array will be something like

[image: Visualized image]

**Deallocation** (`free`):

Notice that `arrayArray` by it self is just a pointer to 4 other pointer. If you want to free the entire array, you don't just free the space for the 4 pointers. You need to free every space these pointer points to, **else you will cause memory leak**. For example you want to free the entire array, it is just the reverse of allocation, first free all the space `arrayArray` points to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    delete[] arrayArray[x];
```

In C++, if you want to `delete` a space allocated by `new something[]`, you need `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Then free the array itself:

```
delete[] arrayArray;
```

Comment: I'm new at c++ please be patient with me. From the drawing.. It looks like arrayarray is point to 4 spaces (freeing up 4 spaces to be used). But then each of them is point to an additional 4 spaces. So it's really freeing up 16 spaces. if I only wanted to free up 4 spaces. Do I need to put                             int**arrayarray instead?

Comment: @myohmy I'm sorry that I don't understand what you are saying, but I add some information about `free`ing, hope that will help you and if you still have any problem please ask me again in comments.

Comment: @myohmy Oh I got you idea. You want a array containing 4 `int`s, see the top of my answer.

Comment: The visual really helped. Thank you! How do you add pictures on here?

Comment: @myohmy This site works by assigning users with reputation score. Higher reputation means more [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). If your are new to this site, see [this tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Basicially adding image is one privileges. If you click the green tick under the big number on the left side of my answer, you accept my answer and I will get 15 reputations.

Comment: ok. Is it possible to send you  a message a here at time? or is that not possible on here. I'm asking because I've been having a lot of difficulties understanding things. Not a lot of people use visuals to explain, and that helps tremendously.

Comment: @myohmy after some search I still don't know. But if you have any thing don't understand in the future, just ask in this site. There are always people that provide helpful explainations and people are welling to answer question here. If you don't understand a answer, you can wait or ask in comments. Also being able to research yourself, using Google, is also a important skill.